# Can't get rid of css list style for Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Would anyone mind taking a look at this?  I can't get rid of the list-style-type decoration on this wordpress widget on this site.

http://www.donhallmark.com/

Here's the code I already have added:

```
.socialMedia ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.socialMedia .widget ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.widget ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.simple-social-icons ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.simple-social-icons ul.aligncenter {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.simple-social-icons ul.aligncenter li {
    list-style-type:none;
}

li.social-facebook {
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul.aligncenter {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with WP, what do you mean by `widget`? Where is it?

Comment: Can you include a page that has the list so we can take a look at the Source Code?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```css
.homeWidget ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

You used the wrong classes.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit adding the bullets is this:

```
class="simple-social-icons"
```

When I added `list-style: none;` to that class, the bullet next to the Facebook icon disappeared. If you don't have access to the stylesheet where that class lives, you'll have to supersede it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add list-style:none; to the following class.

```
.simple-social-icons{
overflow:hidden;
list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in Latest Blog Posts widget, its inheriting this style rule on style.css line #790

```
.homeWidget ul {
  list-style: disc outside none;
}
```